# How to find and then compare similar files in Dropbox folder?

Tags: command-line, unix, shell, dropbox

I am using Dropbox, and I wind up with a number of files like: 
prefs (home's conflicted copy 2009-07-20).js

What I would like to do is find all the "conflicted copy..." files and then compare each with its unconflicted version.

For example, the following command gives me the result:

```
$ find . -name "*onflict*" -exec ls -ld {} \;
-rw-r--r-- 1 eric eric 24203 2009-07-19 14:42 ./prefs (home's conflicted copy 2009-07-20).js
```

but I would like an output like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 eric eric 24429 2009-07-21 11:43 prefs.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 eric eric 24203 2009-07-19 14:42 prefs (home's conflicted copy 2009-07-20).js
```

and then I can decide what I want to do with the conflicted copy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out something that seems to works, but I would welcome suggestions to improve it, including making it cleaner:

```
find . -name "*onflict*" | while read name; do ls -ld "$name"; ls -ld "${name/ (*onflict*)/}"; echo -n "$name" | xargs -0 -p rm ; echo ; done
```

In a more easily read and typed format:

```
find . -name "*onflict*" | \
while read name; do 
    ls -ld "$name"
    ls -ld "${name/ (*onflict*)/}"
    echo -n "$name" | xargs -0 -p rm 
    echo 
done
```

References:

- Using the shell to "mill" over the results of the initial find command- a pipemill 
  [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)#Pipemill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29#Pipemill)
- Manipulating strings in the shell 
  http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8919 
  http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html#SUBSTRREPL00
- Using xargs 
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs 
  http://ss64.com/bash/xargs.html

Answer (score 0):

After you've matched the conflicted filename, use a regular expression to replace the parenthesis and space with a star and do, for example:

```
ls -d "prefs*.js"
```

Comment: BTW, the example ls -d "prefs*.js" is an example of shell filename expansion or shell pattern matching, functionality which is a subset of full regular expresions.

Comment: But how do I apply regular expression to the {} in the find command -exec option?

Comment: You might want to write a perl version of this instead, but I bet it could be written with just a single line using awk/sed, I'm just not proficient enough to describe it.